# Can't run listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm new here. need help I have problem running my apps. this is how my apps operates:

1 I have edit text on layout, so that i can enter it and send it using Button
2 the string in the edit text will be store in array (String[])
3 then I put the String to my ListView
4 So i could the ListView see my input on same screen I input (just like to do apps)

Is it matter with fragment layout?

I can't run it. need help.Thanks

```
ListView listviewtest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewtest);
EditText edittexttest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittexttest);
TextView textviewtest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtest);
int x=0,y=0;
ArrayAdapter m_all_inputlist;
Button buttonenter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontest);

String[] datatest = {""};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutor4);

    buttonenter.setOnClickListener(listener_buttonenter);
}

View.OnClickListener listener_buttonenter = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(y<10)
        {
            y = insertdata(x);
        }
        else
        {
            exceeddatainsert();
        }

        storeinlistview(datatest);
    }
};

private void storeinlistview(String[] datatest)
{

    List<String> all_inputlist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(datatest));

    m_all_inputlist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(null,R.layout.dataentered,R.id.textviewtest, all_inputlist);

    // Get a reference, which is listview, to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    listviewtest.setAdapter(m_all_inputlist);
}

private void exceeddatainsert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder warnexceed = new AlertDialog.Builder(tutor4.this);
    warnexceed.setTitle("Invalid");
    warnexceed.setPositiveButton("add button", insertnewtotal());
    warnexceed.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
    warnexceed.setMessage("You have inserted 10 things");
    warnexceed.create().show();
}

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener insertnewtotal() {
    return null;
}

private int insertdata(int x) {
    datatest[x] = edittexttest.getText().toString();
    x++;
    return x;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tutor4, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: move all the `findViewById` calls, in `onCreate` after `setContentView`

Comment: Also, get rid of `String[] datatest`.   Your data source is `all_inputlist`, so just use that.

Comment: now i dont know why did it replace first string of datatest[] when i input second, third datatest[] onward